# Linking two XML layouts in one java file

Tags: android, xml

I am creating a flashlight app...I want to link two layouts in one java file...one layout is when the torch is unlit...and the other layout shows an illuminating torch...I have worked on it and now when i press the button it shifts to the other layout..(the illuminating one)...but does not come back to the first one when i click the button...What to do?
Here is the code..

My XML1:

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/fl"
tools:context=".Flash" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ib2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bu" />
```

My XML2:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fl1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@id/ib2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bu" />
```

My Flashlight.java file (excluding imports):

```java
    package com.potapptoes.flashlight;
    public class Flash extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Camera cam = null;
Button ib1;
Parameters para;
PowerManager pm;
WakeLock wl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "whatever");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    wl.acquire();
    initialize();
    ib1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ib1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ib2);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (cam == null) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        cam = Camera.open();
        para = cam.getParameters();
        para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cam.setParameters(para);
    } else {
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.setParameters(para);
        cam.release();
        cam = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    cam.setParameters(para);
    cam.release();
    cam = null;
    wl.release();
    finish();
}
    }
```

Comment: In your xml you have ib2 as the button in the first one and in the second it is ib4 which does not have a click listener on it so i believe it is never calling your click listener, you would have to add a click listener to the ib4 button also in order to receive the requests from that button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html).

[Here](http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/using-a-viewswitcher-in-your-android-xml-layouts/) is an example.

Comment: U have given me a path to follow...but i have no idea how to introduce the switcher when i press the button...anyhelp would be appreciable...

Comment: Your two layouts should now be in the one layout file inside a ViewSwitcher. Both layouts have a button - give the buttons each a unique ID. You should have a global variable in your activity referencing the ViewSwitcher in the layout.  Assign both your buttons an OnClickListener. When the button in the first layout is pressed call switcher.showNext(), and when the button in the second layout is pressed call switcher.showPrevious().

Comment: Done!!...Working...thanks alot...:D...but the app is crashing when i am pressing the back button..:/

Comment: Done with that error tooo...I have to use if else statement in the onpause too...Working fine...SOLVED!!...Thanks guysss

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (cam == null) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        cam = Camera.open();
        para = cam.getParameters();
        para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cam.setParameters(para);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.main); // you forgot this line
        para.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.setParameters(para);
        cam.release();
        cam = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you just change background image on button Click?

1. Create **onClickListener** for your button.
2. Create boolean variable which would trigger the flashlight on and off on Click of a button.
3. Change background after you check is the flashlight already "triggered" or not.

Hope I understood your question correct, and you will find this helpful.